# Cocoa: NSRectFill on button click does not work

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Hello I am new to Cocoa programming and I met a problem about NSRectFill.

There is one button in the window, and the following is my AppDelegate.m file:

```
@implementation LGAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect( 50,50,10,10));
}


- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [[NSColor greenColor] set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect( 60,60,10,10));
}
@end
```

What I expected to see is a rectangle shows when the application starts, and another rectangle shows after clicking the button. However, only one rectangle shows, nothing happened after clicking the button. 
Please help me to solve this. Thank you.
Yours,
Z

Comment: First of all, are you sure you connected your button with your IBAction buttonPressed ?

Comment: I am sure the button and the IBAction buttonPressed are connected. (by NSLog(@"buttonPressed"))

Comment: Now I am trying an alternative way:`- (void) drawRect:(NSRect) rectangle withColor:(NSColor *)color
{
    graphicsContextWithWindow:self.window];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithWindow:self.window]];
    
    [[NSColor yellowColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rectangle);
    
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self drawRect:NSMakeRect(77, 77, 7, 77) withColor:[NSColor yellowColor]];
}
@end`   Is this the right way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some background, `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is called at the launch of a program once the program is 'done' loading resources.

But at this point, there could be many windows and many views displayed by the application.  Simply calling `NSRectFill()` is not enough.  The application wouldn't know where to draw said rectangle  (is it in this window or that one? This NSView or that one).  Even if there's only one window and it might seem obvious... there might be multiple NSViews displayed that you're unaware of.... and with computers you have to be very explicit with your commands.

**The bottom line is:** there is no 'context' established for where the drawing actions to occur.  As *d00dle* points out, you should read up on [Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

When an NSView's `drawRect:` is called, a context (itself) has already been set/defined.  You *could* draw directly from your delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` but a 'context' needs to be defined.

Comment: Now I am trying an alternative way:- (void) drawRect:(NSRect) rectangle withColor:(NSColor *)color { graphicsContextWithWindow:self.window]; [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState]; [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithWindow:self.window]]; [[NSColor yellowColor] set]; NSRectFill(rectangle); [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState]; } - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender { [self drawRect:NSMakeRect(77, 77, 7, 77) withColor:[NSColor yellowColor]]; } @end Is this the right way? Thank you.

Comment: The easiest thing you could do is [create a custom view (subclass NSView)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW4), put that view in your window and implement the view's [drawRect:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW23) with your `NSRectFill()` calls. With this you don't need to bother with *graphics contexts* at all. (Check the examples)

Comment: Also, your comment contains way to much code making it hard to read.  Next time maybe update your question with your extra code.

Answer (score 3):

well you don't have any context, the system has no idea where you want to draw.
if you want to draw on a view or an image you have to use a lockFocus / unlockFocus pair.

so if you have a view as an outlet called redView

```
[redView lockFocus];
[[NSColor redColor] set];
NSRectFill(NSMakeRect( 50,50,10,10));
[redView unlockFocus];
```

but this is a really poor model, you generally want your objects to draw themselves.

when a views drawRect: method is called you already have focus and don't need the lock unlock pair

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at apple's [Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)