# Cocoa Programming: Adding a Rectangle to a Custom View (NSView)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, xcode5

Is there a simple way to add a simple rectangle to a Custom View without using a custom NSView subclass for it? Something along the lines of:

1. Assign an IBOutlet (let's call it colorWheelView) of NSView type to the CustomView
2. In my NSViewController's initWithNibName use it to change draw the rectangle:

   `// pseudocode`

   `self.colorWheelView.addRectangle(myRectangle);`

   `self.redraw()`

The only way I've seen it done (on this site, and in my book Cocoa Programming for Mac OSX, pp. 241) is by making a custom class for the Custom View and modifying its drawRect method... Is this really the only way to accomplish this?

Edit: not sure why formatting is not being rendered correctly.  I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241782/cocoa-nsrectfill-on-button-click-does-not-work/17251985#17251985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really isn't all that hard to roll your own..

Just add an `NSArray` property to your `NSView` subclass, then in your `drawRect` method draw them either manually or using one of the `NSRectFillList*` methods provided by AppKit already.
 (**Beware:** those take a plain C array, *not* an `NSArray`).

You wouldn't want to manually trigger the redraw from outside the view as in your sample code, though. To keep things consistent your `addRectangle` would trigger a redraw of the view itself e.g. by calling `setNeedsDisplay:`.